# Why does this random string generator perform so poorly?

Tags: php, random

I found this bit of PHP code for generating random strings (alphabetical, alphanumeric, numeric, and hexadecimal).

```php
<?php
function random($length = 8, $seeds = 'alpha') {
  // Possible seeds
  $seedings['alpha'] = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyz';
  $seedings['numeric'] = '0123456789';
  $seedings['alphanum'] = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyz0123456789';
  $seedings['hexidec'] = '0123456789abcdef';

  // Choose seed
  if (isset($seedings[$seeds])) {
    $seeds = $seedings[$seeds];
  }

  // Seed generator
  list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
  $seed = (float) $sec + ((float) $usec * 100000);
  mt_srand($seed);

  // Generate
  $str = '';
  $seeds_count = strlen($seeds);

  for ($i = 0; $length > $i; $i++) {
    $str .= $seeds{mt_rand(0, $seeds_count - 1)};
  }

  return $str;
}
?>
```

If I run this function with the default arguments (so it is generating 8 character strings, alphabetical only) and generate 1,000,000 strings, I'd think my collision rate would be low:

```
26^8 = 208,827,064,576
1,000,000 / 208,827,064,576 ~= 0.0004%
```

In actuality, when I run that on my machine, I get a 90% collision rate! Only 10% of my generated strings are unique.

Actually, it is suspiciously close to 10%. Generating multiple sets of 1,000,000 random strings, I find that each set generates...

1. **100,032** unique strings
2. **100,035** unique strings
3. **100,032** unique strings
4. **100,028** unique strings
5. **100,030** unique strings
6. *you get the idea...*

So what gives? Obviously it has to do with how I'm seeding `mt_srand`, or how php implements `mt_rand`, or something else.

So...

#### Why doesn't this code generate useful random strings?

#### And what would be a better approach?

Comment: codereview or maths would be a better place i would say

Comment: Have you tried it without seeding?

Comment: @dagon Since this isn't asking for a review, Code Review would not be a good fit.

Comment: programming perhaps.

Comment: @Dagon It is most certainly not [on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Code Review.

Comment: well im glad that's all sorted then. i never post there so my bad

Comment: A few things I noticed: 1) It looks like `mt_srand` is supposed to take an int, but you give it a float. Why is that? 2) The documentation for `mt_srand` seems to indicate that it is not actually necessary to use it. "Note: There is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() or mt_srand() as this is done automatically." 3) A user note in that same documentation (if it is correct) says "Looks like mt_rand() gives same result for different seeds when the lowest bits are different only."

Comment: I may be completely wrong, but is this function generating strings based on a high-resolution timestamp? Because if so, the answer is probably "the timestamp isn't high-resolution enough". Would also conveniently explain why your # of unique strings is 1/10 of the total.

Comment: I cant find the post, but it describes with multiplying the unique number, it will decrease the uniqueness. something to do with mathematics statistics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the seed unless you know what you're doing, from the manual:

> Note: There is no need to seed the random number generator with
>   srand() or mt_srand() as this is done automatically.

The following code gets me almost a set of 100% unique strings

```
<?php
  function random($length = 8, $charset = 'alpha'){
    $list = [
      'alpha' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyz',
      'numeric' => '0123456789',
      'alphanum' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwqyz0123456789',
      'hexidec' => '0123456789abcdef'
    ];

    if(!isset($list[$charset])){
      trigger_error("Invalid charset '$charset', allowed sets: '".implode(', ', array_keys($list))."'", E_USER_NOTICE);
      $charset = 'alpha';
    }

    $str   = '';
    $max   = strlen($list[$charset]) - 1;

    for ($i = 0; $length > $i; $i++) {
      $str .= $list[$charset][mt_rand(0, $max)];
    }

    return $str;
  }

  $loop = 1000000;

  for($i=0;$i<$loop;$i++){
    $arr[random()] = true;
  }

  echo $loop - count($arr), " dupes found in list.";
?>
```

Comment: how do you check for uniqueness? i want to play around with this and jsut wasnet sure of a good apporach

Comment: yhea, i thought of that, its the array of 1000000 entries i was worried about ;-)

Comment: @Dagon You'll see his code is setting the index `$arr[random()]` with  1000000 iterations, if the index already exists it will basically end with a final result of less than 1000000

Comment: Thanks! Yep, using my seed method turned out to be _awful_, and not seeding is way better. Just ran my code without `mt_srand` and got 999,998 unique strings out of 1,000,000.